# Similar jQuery Menu System

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, menu

Would anyone know of a jQuery plugin that is very similar to this style of menu found here:
[menu example](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/accessible-expanding-collapsing-menu/)

Really looking for the same look and feel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-mootools-homepage-inspired-navigation-effect-using-jquery/

try these link